# SQL Server: CONVERT From ISO8601 To DateTime Within Query

Tags: sql-server, type-conversion, cast

I have a Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 database where the `DateTime` column is not a `datetime` data type, but `varchar(50)`. Our website logs that data and I don't really have control over it (I'm sure a proper `datetime` column would be preferable). I'm trying to do a query that gets some year-to-date results with `BETWEEN DateTime field AND NOW()`.

SQL Server table:

```
Id  DateTime                    Ip              City            State       Country         Continent   UserAgent
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1   2013-02-05T17:58:45-06:00   68.55.34.32     Laurel          Maryland    United States   North America   NULL
2   2013-02-05T17:58:52-06:00   70.88.57.62     Port Charlotte  Florida     United States   North America   NULL
3   2013-02-05T17:59:06-06:00   71.3.202.110    Cape Coral      Florida     United States   North America   NULL
4   2013-02-05T17:59:23-06:00   67.239.18.161   Naples          Florida     United States   North America   NULL
5   2013-02-05T17:59:58-06:00   96.19.107.135   Gulfport        Mississippi United States   North America   NULL
```

SQL query:

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.RebroadcastSmoothStreaming
WHERE 
   (DateTime BETWEEN CONVERT(datetime, SUBSTRING('2014-01-01T00:00:00-06:00', 1, 19)) AND { fn NOW() })
ORDER BY Ip
```

I'm getting an error

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

This query works...

```
SELECT CONVERT(datetime, SUBSTRING('2014-01-01T00:00:00-06:00', 1, 19)) AS Expr1
```

I've also tried `CAST()`...

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.RebroadcastSmoothStreaming
WHERE (DateTime BETWEEN CAST(SUBSTRING('2014-01-01T00:00:00-06:00', 1, 19) AS datetime) AND { fn NOW() })
ORDER BY Ip
```

That gives the same conversion error, but this works...

```
SELECT CAST(SUBSTRING('2014-01-01T00:00:00-06:00', 1, 19) AS datetime) AS Expr1
```

I'm sure that I'm missing some fundamental bit, but it seems like it should work.

What am I doing incorrectly?

JJ

Comment: Do all the values have the `-06:00` or does the timezone offset vary?

Comment: `> not a datetime data type, but varchar(50)` WHY? WHY? WHY?

Comment: @ypercube Sometimes, it is `-05:00`.  I'm not really concerned with the specific times.  I was just trying to get some year-to-date figures.  That why I was trying to convert to a datetime type (so that I could use `NOW()`).

Comment: @AaronBertrand Why?  Because I thought that a time format that included an offset would be better than one that didn't.  Plus, that data is being pushed from a website and I didn't know how to push that data as a datetime (string and int, I know).  It was something that needed to be done and I did it to the best of my ability, at the time.  It was a simple lack of knowledge.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that you cannot `CONVERT` or `CAST` a `VARCHAR` ISO8601 datetime with an offset to a `DATETIME`.

From SQL Server 2008 onwards, the `DATETIMEOFFSET` datatype was introduced to handle datetimes with offsets.

As answered elsewhere, you would need to `CAST` your DateTime `VARCHAR` column to a `DATETIMEOFFSET`

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.RebroadcastSmoothStreaming
WHERE 
   (
       CAST(DateTime AS DATETIMEOFFSET) BETWEEN 
         CAST('2014-01-01T00:00:00-06:00 AS DATETIMEOFFSET) 
         AND { fn NOW() }
   )
ORDER BY Ip
```

Comment: Choosing this as the answer only because it is the one that most does what I was trying to do (not that it is necessarily the best way).  Also, thanks for including that `DATETIMEOFFSET` will only work on SQL Server 2008 and newer.  ypercube's answer may be better for older versions.

Comment: Interestingly enough, the two other answers gave the same number of results.  This answer was less, by 20ish.  We're talking about 15000ish results, so the discrepancy isn't huge.  I wonder if the difference is in `dateadd()` versus `NOW()`?

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just use?:

```
WHERE DateTime >= '2014-01-01'
  AND DateTime < CONVERT(CHAR(19), DATEADD(second, 1, GETDATE()), 126)
```

**Advantages:**
 - No values in the `varchar` column will be converted so you'll get no errors
 - Efficiency as indexes can be used

**Disadvantages:**
 - does not take care of timezone offsets
 - some of the values, while being invalid as datetimes (examples `'2014-01-33T25:61:62'`, `'2014 Sunday 13th of April'`), they will still be returned by the query.

Comment: I'll have to test that out.  I didn't think about converting the current time to iso8601.  I was trying to convert iso8601 to datetime.

Answer (score 1):

Try type casting to `datetimeoffset` type as below:

```
CAST(datetime as DATETIMEOFFSET)
```

For instance your query will become something like following:

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.RebroadcastSmoothStreaming
WHERE (CAST(datetime as DATETIMEOFFSET)
BETWEEN CAST('2014-01-01T00:00:00-06:00' AS datetimeoffset) 
AND dateadd(day, 1, SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()))
ORDER BY Ip
```

Comment: Oh, I wonder if part of the problem was that I was just doing `DateTime` in the `WHERE` clause.  I see that you're actually doing `CAST()`, twice.  I was only doing it, once.